# How do i use `selectGraphQLResultFromTable` to load relations for a Sequelize query in a post-graphile resolver?

Tags: sequelize.js, postgraphile

I have in my database a couple of related tables:

`rooms` table:

```
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "details" jsonb,
    "metadata" jsonb,
    "region" character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uk'::character varying,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "houseId" integer REFERENCES houses(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

`houses` table:

```
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "coordinates" jsonb,
    "type" jsonb NOT NULL,
    "region" character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uk'::character varying,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "blockId" integer REFERENCES blocks(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT "houses_originalProdId_region_key" UNIQUE ("originalProdId", region)
```

In my project, I use PostGraphile (graphile-utils) as my GraphQL provider.

I created a custom resolver to execute dynamically-built complex queries on `rooms` using Sequelize.
I chose to query the DB through Sequelize and not directly through PostGraphile because various parts of the query object are built dynamically (the `where` object and the `include` array).

The resolver looks like this:

```js
async (_query, args) => {
      const { input, pagination } = args;

      const filteredRooms = await roomRepository.findRoomsUsingDynamicFilters(
        pagination,
        input,
      );

      return filteredRooms || null;
    }
```

This query works, but now relations cannot be loaded for rooms, so I can’t query `house` through my relevant filtered rooms:

```
{
  filterRooms(input: { filterByAttributes: ["large", "white"] }, pagination: {}) {
    house{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Results in

```
{
  "data": {
    "filterRooms": [
      {
        "house": null
      },
      {
        "house": null
      },
      {
        "house": null
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

In the PostGraphile docs I’ve found the method `selectGraphQLResultFromTable` which seems to load relations, but I’m unsure how to use it in conjunction with the Sequelize query; that is, how can my resolver return only the rooms that I’ve filtered through Sequelize, in a format that will enable the querying of their relations (like in the example above)?